# Subroutine with array element as argument

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, subroutine

In my program subroutine `stlstp` passing `work(2,1)` as parameter to `stlfts(...)` subroutine. `work(2,1)` will be double value at that index, but how subroutine converting it as single dimension array `x(n)`?

When I print `x` value in `stlfts(...)` subroutine, it is printing elements of `n` size, example:

```
 STLFTS....X,,,   0.0000000000000000        1.4964418382246345E-317   1.48978578
58438612E-317   1.4964339331743010E-317   1.4964418382246345E-317   4.3367611401 ....
```

My understanding is, except 1st value, all other values in this `x` are garbage, but not sure how this assignment will will effect original reference? can someone please help me with this?

```
subroutine stlstp(y,n,np,ns,nt,nl,isdeg,itdeg,ildeg,nsjump,ntjump,nljump,ni,userw,rw,season,trend,work)

!     implicit none
! Arg
      integer n,np,ns,nt,nl,isdeg,itdeg,ildeg,nsjump,ntjump,nljump,ni
      logical userw
      double precision y(n),rw(n),season(n),trend(n),work(20,5)
! Var
      integer i,j

     do 80 j = 1,1
         do 1 i = 1,n
              work(i,1) = y(i)-trend(i)
 1       continue
         call stlss(y,n,np,ns,isdeg,nsjump,userw,rw,season)

         PRINT *, 'WORK 1,2 ....',work(1,2)
         PRINT *, 'WORK ....',work
         call stlfts(work(1,2),n+2*np,np,work(1,3),work(1,1))
```

Now `stlfts` subroutine code is:

```
  subroutine stlfts(x,n,np,trend,work)
    integer n, np
    double precision x(n), trend(n), work(n)
    PRINT *, 'STLFTS....X,,,',x 
    call stlma(x,    n,      np, trend)
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, to IanH for the direction to the standard (Fortran 2008 12.5.2.11(1)), the answer was wrong in the statement about the standard conformance:

> An actual argument represents an element sequence if it is an array
>   expression, **an array element designator**, a default character scalar,
>   or a scalar of type character with the C character kind (15.2.2). If
>   the actual argument is an array expression, the element sequence
>   consists of the elements in array element order. **If the actual
>   argument is an array element designator, the element sequence consists
>   of that array element and each element that follows it in array
>   element order.**

This means this praxis is standard conforming and this is a legal way how to pass a part of an array starting from some element.

The situation can be explained to C programmers as the subroutine `stlstp` passing the address of the actual point in the original array.

The subroutine `stlfts` then interprets the address as an address of a part of the original array of length `n`. It will be the first `n` elements in the column major order starting from the element `(1,2)`. This way it gets access to other elements of the original array `WORK` and the result will not be garbage.

Comment: Thanks! Yes it is pretty old code, I am trying to reverse engineer it.Can you point me to some example on internet to understand more about "It will be the first n elements in the column major order starting from the element (1,2)"? An example in action will help me to quickly understand the concept.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order Otherwise just understand it as passing `&work[2][1]` and expecting `double x[n]` or `double *x` in C (provided `work` is contiguous as old Fortran arrays are).

Comment: Thank you! I think I am little bit clear on this topic. I am writing a quick small example to validate my understanding.

Comment: I am assuming same principle applies to "single dimension arrays" too. Am I correct?

Comment: Sure, it is even simpler for them.

Comment: Thank you! simpler in terms of no column ordering confusion right? they are simple continuous items.

Comment: Exactly, the ordering is simple.

Comment: Standard or not, this is such a pervasive practice (not to mention the stuff of textbooks) that any compiler that breaks it will end up in the garbage.  Just by the way in the example `work(1,2),work(2,2)..` are never set (unless set outside `stlstp`)