# Is there any reason to pass array by first item?

Tags: arrays, fortran, subroutine

In a rather old style Fortran project, I often see this pattern, when an array is passed by its first item:

```
program test
    implicit none
    integer :: a(10)
    a(:) = 1
    call sub(a(1), 10) ! here
contains
    subroutine sub(a, length)
        integer, intent(in) :: length
        integer, intent(in) :: a(length)
        print *, a
    end subroutine
end program
```

where it could be:

```
    call sub(a, 10) ! here
```

which is valid even in Fortran 77.

Note the size of the array has to be passed and used explicitly, this will not work for assumed shape array:

```
    subroutine sub(a)
        integer, intent(in) :: a(:)
        print *, a
    end subroutine
```

For me this is confusing, as the call suggests a scalar is passed to the subroutine. I suppose it works because the array is passed by reference.

Is there any reason to pass arrays like this, especially now?

Comment: It works because it is allowed by the standard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000321/subroutine-with-array-element-as-argument  Not sure if the question, whether there are now reasons to use it or bot *now* is off-topic.

Comment: For example, it is used when passing array sections in certain cases when using  MPI non-blocking subroutines in MPI 2. But now we have the possibility of mpi_f08 in MPI 3. Does it mean there is a reason to pass it *now* or not?

Comment: Note the size of the array does not have to be passed explicitly. The subroutine may now it through some other means.

Comment: IMO, the main reason that this method is allowed is for legacy code.  I agree that it's confusing and would not recommend using it unless there is a good reason.

Answer (score 3):

One uses this feature when using the older interface to the non-blocking MPI routines.

Say you want to pass subarray `A(10,10:19)` which is a part of a bigger array `A(1:100,1:100)`.

If you pass

```
use mpi
call ISend(A(10,10:19), 10, MPI_REAL, ...
```

you pass a temporary copy of array A and the address of the temporary copy will not be valid at the time of the MPI_Wait. Therefore, instead, you create an MPI derived type, that describes the offsets in the array to be sent and you use it as

```
use mpi
call ISend(A(10,10), 1, derived_type, ...
```

Of course, with the most modern MPI libraries and compilers you use `use mpi_f08`. However, most HPC codes in the wild do not use it yet.

Another solution is to use an MPI derived type that includes the absolute address of the subarray and just pass `A`. Sometimes it is practical, sometimes it is not. It depends on how much the subarrays passed vary throughout the code.

Be aware that there are other issues present in non-blocking MPI in the old interface and it helps if you explicitly mark the routines as `ASYNCHRONOUS`.

Comment: This reminds me of the recent MPI users [survey](https://bosilca.github.io/MPIsurvey/) report where a small percentage of respondents think MPI datatypes are useless... Maybe they belong to the type (pun intended) that sticks to Gropp's famous [six-function MPI](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/tutorial/gropp/node52.html)?

Comment: I see the need you describe, but in my case it is not used for MPI calls.

Comment: @Neraste This was just an example. Your code will have some other reason, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following example:

```
  implicit none

  integer a(2,2)
  a = RESHAPE([1,2,3,4],[2,2])

  call sub(a(2,1))
  print '(2I3)', TRANSPOSE(a)

contains

  subroutine sub(b)
    integer, intent(out) :: b(2)
    b = -1
  end subroutine sub

end
```

Here, the element sequence represented by the actual argument `a` is `a(2,1), a(1,2), a(2,2)`, and the first two are associated with the dummy argument `b`.

For arrays of rank greater than one, this element sequence use may make things (much) easier to specify certain consecutive elements of the actual argument. For a rank-1 array we can write `a(3:)` instead of `a(3)`, say, as the actual argument. For higher rank arrays we haven't that option.

I won't express an opinion on whether this is a good use this feature.